# When navigating via deep link, how is nav graph constructed internally if the app has multiple nav graphs and they are nested

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation, android-deep-link

I have an app with multiple nav graphs and I would like for my deep link destination to always go to `start` destination when pressing back. The deep links, somehow, end up in a different graph and when I press back they do not go back to `start`, but to `explore`. What decides which graph will be used when the app is entered through an implicit deep link?

The app I am working with has `main_navigation` graph (which consists of four other graphs - tabs in bottom navigation):

```
<navigation
    android:id="@+id/navigation_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/startTab">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/start" />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/explore" />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/my_page" />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/settings" />
```

My `start` graph, which is supposed to be the first destination in the nav stack, includes:

```
<navigation
    android:id="@+id/startTab"
    android:label="@string/tabs_start"
    app:startDestination="@id/startPageDest">

<include app:graph="@navigation/details" />
```

The `details` is a graph which contains a destination that is used from a lot of different places in the app. It is, for example, also included in `explore` graph.

```
<navigation
    android:id="@+id/exploreTab"
    app:startDestination="@id/exploreDest">

<include app:graph="@navigation/details" />
```

I've added a deep link to `details`:

```
<navigation
    android:id="@+id/detailsGraph"
    app:startDestination="@id/detailsDest">

<deepLink app:uri="test.com/details/{id}" />
```

and it works, but the back stack is not correct.